# scaling image on pinch recognzer gesture IOS

Tags: ios, zooming, scale, pinchzoom, uipinchgesturerecognizer

i am using a pinch gesture and scroll view to zoom the image in image view .

pinch and zoom works fine ,

but I need to print the pinch zoom scale which is how much scale the image is zoomed(i.e: 1 or  or 3)

i tried everything , please help to finish this thing. i am worried with it for days ,

post any code for it , or reference for it ,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use UIScrollView instead of gesture recogniser. It has built-in methods that handle everything for you. You may find this helpful : http://vimeo.com/1642150 and a simple code shows how to do http://snipplr.com/view/66620/scrolling-panning-zooming-with-uiscrollview/

Comment: Actually i need to use p[inch gesture to recognize the pinch scale , can u refer any other thing with pinch gesture . thanks .